# Displaying data in Excel graph only up to current date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, date-time, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel chart that displays 5 sets of data in a single scatter plot, where the X axis is the date of occurrence. In my table, I have both actual values from previous dates and projected values for the upcoming few months. Is there a way using conditional formatting to:

Display the data in different shades? Actual data from previous days would be full color, while projected data for upcoming dates are in a shaded color? The graph should adjust automatically as days progress and actual data is input (if it differs from the projected value).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by:

- adding a calculated column where you insert whether the date is in the past:
  (`=TODAY()>A2`)
- insert a pivot chart and set:

  - Legend (series): `series` and `past` (column D)
  - axis (categories): date
  - values: value
  - What you can't do is to make the line continuous across time, Excel consider them as different series

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having to use the "series" column with the A or B between different data sets? Right now, my columns are:

Date, Series 1, Series 2, Series 3, Past

Comment: Have you tried adding both series1 and series2 to values? It should work.

Comment: But for your picture, you had the "value" column holding both sets of data, and separating the two by the "series" column with A and B. If I added both series1 and series2 to values, what would I have in my "series" column?

Comment: Then you don't need to have a "series" column. I've done my best guess to answer your question based on the data you've provided. Please play around a bit with the pivot chart and I'm sure you'll find the solution.